# Cannot populate json field from scratch using Lockbox gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm storing my client settings in a JSON object and am trying to encrypt that object using the Lockbox gem.

Here's the section from my model:

```
  store :settings, accessors: %i[currency]
  encrypts :settings
```

When I load up a client model (with an empty settings field) and try and save the currency like this:

```
client=Client.first
client.currency="USD"
client.save
```

Nothing is saved and both client.settings and client.currency return nil.  If I add a random item to the hash, for example:

```
client=Client.first 
client.settings={:test=>"test"}
client.currency="USD"
client.save
```

This saves as expected and client.currency returns "USD" and client.settings returns `{:test=>"test", :currency=>"USD"}`

Why can I not set the currency when the settings field is empty?